# Laravel conditional array using Resource

Tags: laravel

I've got People table with columns: `person`, `name`, `text`.
column person can have only values like: `physician`, `dentist`, `nurse`, etc...

I want to send it via api using Laravel Resource, so I created basic `PeopleResource.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class PeopleResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'text' => $this->text
        ];
    }
}
```

this is simple and gives me an array of objects with name and text.

Now I want to make more complicated array that will give me something like this:

`Please note` that I want to get all person types into my array here. This is the problem of making my array structured - so I can access it like result.physician.name, result.nurse.name etc..

```
result: {
 physician: [{name: "name1", text: "text2"}, {name: "name2", text: "text2"}...],
 nurse: [{name: "name1", text: "text2"}, {name: "name2", text: "text2"}...],
 dentist: [{name: "name1", text: "text2"}, {name: "name2", text: "text2"}...],
 otherTypeOfPerson: [], ....
}
```

How can I do it using Laravel Resource?

edit: my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\People;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\PeopleResource;

class PeoplesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $peoples= People::orderBy('id','asc')->get();

        return PeopleResource::collection($peoples);
    }
```

edit2: I was thinking about this solution, but this seems not working:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        if($this->person == 'nurse') {
            'nurse' => [
                'name' => $this->name,
                'text' => $this->text                   
            ]
        }
        if($this->person == 'physician') {
            'physician' => [
                'name' => $this->name,
                'text' => $this->text                   
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: use `groupBy()` on collection

Comment: @Sohel0415 thanks for this tip, can I ask for some basic example?

Comment: something like `User::where('id','!=',0)->get()->groupBy('status')->toArray();` and it would be good if you share your controller logic/code that others can help you

Comment: @Sohel0415 let me see if it works now

Comment: @Sohel0415 I added controller

Comment: I wrote `$peoples = People::orderBy('id','asc')->get()->groupBy('people')->toArray();` but this gives me error: `"message": "Call to a member function first() on array"`

Comment: add full code,, what you have tried,, see my answer, you may have an idea

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = YourModel:groupBy('person')->get();
dd($result);
```

//define your field name in model

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy()` on collection.

```
public function index()
{
    $peoples = People::select(['name', 'text', 'person'])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

    return $peoples->groupBy('person')->toArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm checking... The code is just the same as in the question. Nothing special

Comment: just try it, you will know the differences

Comment: where shoud I use this code? Sorry for stupid question, but database query should be in controller, and return of the controller should be `return PeopleResource::collection($peoples);`

Comment: I don't really understand. I've changed my code in controller to: `$peoples = People::select(['name', 'text', 'person'])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
$peoples->groupBy('person')->toArray();
return PeopleResource::collection($peoples);`

Comment: please show your latest controller after added my code and also include what is error and where its occurring error??

Comment: not changing the PeopleResource, and this changed nothting, but no errors now

Comment: I thinkt that it is not a matter of groupBy but the PeopleResouce code - to make the right structure of the result array

Comment: you can't use resource for your task, atleast what you are looking for

Comment: see my updated answer, hope it helps you and you can't do what you are trying to achieve with that changes

Comment: sorry it's not solving my problem, but thank you for helping me!